# Thick vertical lines in tabularhtx (or any other fit-the-page table)?

Tags: tables

I am trying to layout a table filling the whole page (so far I am working with `tabularhtx`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[vlines]{tabularht}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
    \begin{tabularhtx}{\textheight}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
        % A "header" row with bolder lines
        \noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
            \interrowfill
             & \\
            \interrowfill
        \noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
            \interrowfill
             & \\
            \interrowfill
        \hline
            \interrowfill
             & \\
            \interrowfill
        \noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
    \end{tabularhtx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Now all that is left would be making the outer *vertical* borders "bold" as well. But when I try this...

```
\begin{tabularhtx}{\textheight}{\textwidth}{!{\vrule width 2pt}X|X!{\vrule width 2pt}}
```

...the results are not satisfactory, as this does not work with `tabularhtx`'s `\interrowfill` (the inserted spacing interrupts the vertical lines).

Is there some way I can have a table, stretched to page size, with configurable width of the vertical lines?

Answer (score 1):

A work-around with `\fbox`, and a slight simplification of the code with the `boldline` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[vlines]{tabularht}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}
    \fbox{\begin{tabularhtx}{\textheight}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
            \interrowfill
             & \\
            \interrowfill
    \hlineB{5}
            \interrowfill
             & \\
            \interrowfill
        \hline
            \interrowfill
             & \\
            \interrowfill
    \end{tabularhtx}}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The result looks good. But you copied my code into your answer, not yours. ;-)

Comment: Oops! Sorry – a clipboard accident. That's fixed now. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: While your answer has helped me, I am leaving this question open for now in case someone has a solution for the more general case -- your way wouldn't help with any of the inner lines for example.

Comment: Do you mean thick inner vertical lines?